# Can't stop Blackberry Screen Vertically Scrolling in phonegap

Tags: css, cordova, jquery-mobile

[image]

Hi,
I have developed a screen using jquery mobile for Blackberry using phonegap. But when I deploy it to device the screen scrolls vertically as shown in the image below. I tried the same html,css,js combination with the android device phonegap project and it doesn't scroll at all. It seems to be scrolling vertically only in blackberry. Is there any way we could disable vertical scroll bars in blackberry in a phonegap project ?. The horizontal scrolling is disabled successfully though.

Any help with regard to this is highly appreciated. I am using dreamweaver to design the ui and js. and using the command line(terminal) to build and deploy to the blackberry device.

My code is as shown below :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" id="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-       height,initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no;"/>
    <title>jQuery Mobile Web App</title>

    <link href="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="jquery-mobile/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="js/application.js">
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
    #page{
    overflow: hidden;
    }
    </style>
    <script type="application/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var width = $(window).width(),
        height = $(window).height() - $("#header").height(),
        row = height / 2,
        iconTopSpace = (Number(row) - 50) / 2;          
        $("div ul li a").attr("style", "height:"+row+"px");
        $(".ui-btn-inner").attr("style","margin-top:"+iconTopSpace+"px");
});
    </script>

    </head> 
    <body> 

    <div data-role="page" id="page">

<div data-role="header" id="header">
    <h1>Our Workplace</h1>
</div>



    <!-- Do this for the blackberry with a higher screen width -->

    <div data-role="navbar">
<ul>
    <li><a href="Ourworkplace.html" data-transition="slide"  data-iconpos="bottom" data-icon="our-workplace">Our Workplace</a></li>
    <li><a href="b.html" data-transition="slide" data-iconpos="bottom" data-icon="find-your-way" onClick="test()">Find your way</a></li>
    <li><a href="b.html" data-transition="slide" data-iconpos="bottom" data-icon="technology">Technology</a></li>
</ul>
     </div>
     <div data-role="navbar">
 <ul>
 <li><a href="a.html" data-transition="slide" data-iconpos="bottom" data-icon="have-an-idea">Have an Idea</a></li>
    <li><a href="b.html" data-transition="slide" data-iconpos="bottom" data-icon="useful-links">Useful links</a></li>
    <li><a href="b.html" data-transition="slide" data-iconpos="bottom" data-icon="help-desk">Help desk</a></li>
</ul>
    </div>


    </div>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your viewport content : target-densitydpi=device-dpi